# Compressing and Decompressing Folders in C#

Tags: c#, .net, compression, gzipstream

I want to compress and decompress a folder using C#. The problem with GZipStream is that it takes filenames and hence I need to write a recursive logic.

Can I somehow do it like, give source folder name and destination filename to compress the complete folder with hierarchy. I need to do vice-versa for de-compressing the folder as well.
If its not possible through C#/.net directly please suggest some Free 3rd party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GZip only ever deals with single files, which is why under *nix you end up having to archive them into a TAR file first which is then compressed.

If you want multiple files/folders you'll need a format which supports it, like ZIP.

You might want to thus look at: http://www.sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/

Answer (score 8):

I've used the free [SharpZipLib](http://www.sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) multiple times and I'd recommend that you take a look at it. It's quite easy to use and have worked well for all my use cases.

Answer (score 3):

Now included in .NET 4.5 if you'd rather stay off non microsoft libs.

[System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look  at [this library](http://www.sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) Lib.